# How to change header from full-width to box width

Tags: css

I'm using a custom theme on my website.

What I'd like to do is have the header to be boxed while having the main content staying as is.

I've looked at several other threads, but I couldn't manage to make my way to the solution with the theme.

here is my header CSS that makes its full width

```
.full-width-content .wrap, .full-width-content .content-sidebar-wrap {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 100%;
width: 100%;}
```

Comment: either post your full code or provide a live example. without that how can we help?

Comment: I provide the link first but someone said me to remove the link

Comment: http://drketo.jjcreative.info/blog/. Here is the live example

Comment: without seeing the problem, we can't help. you should provide all the details you can give. and be more clear. what do you mean *to be boxed*? to you, it may be crystal clear, but to others it may not

Comment: Did you see the live website I provide you with the link

Comment: Okkey in my website its header is full width but I want it to be boxed as its content

Comment: like this? https://pasteboard.co/I9B2wnk.png

Comment: Yes I just want this

Comment: Added as an answer, if it works for you, the you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reduce the width of your header ,

you can do few different methods.

If you use bootstrap, add class *container* to your header, which will add left and right padding to the element.

Or you can add your own css. With the given url, I found that your header's wrap class can be updated to get you a custom width. so here it is,

```
.site-container header.site-header.fixed .wrap{width: 80%;}
```

you can change the value as you wish